# Connect Galaxy S3 to Wi-Fi ad hoc network

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3, ad-hoc-networks

Are there any tricks/tips to connect my Samsung Galaxy S3 to Wi-Fi ad hoc network shared by my laptop?

Comment: [Enabling AdHoc Networking on ICS to Connect to AdHoc Devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22131), [How to make an unrooted phone use or detect Ad-Hoc Wi-Fi](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/31947), [How can I establish an AD-HOC Wi-Fi connection on my tablet?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26896), [Enable Adhoc on Jelly Bean](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32292)

Comment: Are you rooted? What version of Android are you on? Have you tried any of the solutions in the above question (or anything in the `ad-hoc-networks` tag)?